# Is my swap encrypted or not?

Tags: lubuntu, encryption, swap

I chose to encrypt the home folder while installing Lubuntu 12.10 (64-bit), but after that, sometimes I get error that the system "cannot find /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 wait for mount or cancel at splash screen". Then, Lubuntu starts without any problems.

`blkid` shows

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="fce3ef14-a9c6-45ac-81f5-18ff415851b0" TYPE="swap"
```

That means swap is encrypted, but if I go to Gparted, it shows an unknown partition with a red exclamation mark for swap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is allright, your swap is encrypted, gparted just does not detect the encrypted swap as it is encrypted.