# Swap encrypted with ecryptfs : on which partition is it?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap, ecryptfs

I used ecryptfs to encrypt my home and the swap.
Now I have a device /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 which seems to act as the swap.
(by the way, how can I confirm that?)

Before, my swap was in a partition of its own, sda7.
Now, this partition is shown unused by Gparted (0.00b used).

Therefore I'm wondering if cryptswap1 is located in sda7 or in sda6, which is my ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

sudo blkid | grep swap
/dev/sda5: UUID="blah-blah" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="more stuff"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="blah-blah-blah" TYPE="swap"

From what I gather, since you have cryptswap1, you have an encrypted swap area.  Now, /dev/sda5 still exists, but isn't used, so my thought is no, it isn't used.

An older answer:

[Is my swap encrypted or not?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221651/is-my-swap-encrypted-or-not)

also brings this issue up.